# How to change CPU ID

Tags: c#

How do I change my cpu id I know how to get it yet I have no clue how to change it I really need help. Im using this code:

```
private string getCPUID()
{
    string cpuInfo = "";
    ManagementClass managClass = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
    ManagementObjectCollection managCollec = managClass.GetInstances();

    foreach (ManagementObject managObj in managCollec)
    {
        if (cpuInfo == "")
        {
            //Get only the first CPU's ID
            cpuInfo = managObj.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }

    return cpuInfo;
}
```

Comment: You could change your processor...

Comment: You could find a virtual machine that emulates a different processor.

Comment: The ID of the processor is a hardware ID, so you cannot change it. You could patch windows DLL's (big level of assembly required) but not with c#. Do note c# calls windows DLL's behind the scenes.

Comment: Why do you need to change your CPU ID?

Comment: Also note that this code might not return any CPUID.

Comment: I believe this would be possible via process injection. or other way is to compile virtualbox with changing [DevFwCommon.cpp#L210](https://github.com/mirror/vbox/blob/master/src/VBox/Devices/PC/DevFwCommon.cpp#L210)

Answer (score 0):

Per MSDN:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-processor

ProcessorId

Data type: string

Access type: Read-only

This value comes from the Processor ID member of the Processor Information structure in the SMBIOS information.

There's no way to do this from c# code.  The use cases I know for this involve using some sort of VM or Hypervisor solution  that lets you emulate different harware.  This is sometimes helpful for things like a VPN client that enforces  being on physical hardware and not a VM.

Answer (score -2):

I can't tell you how to change CPU Id's because I don't think that's possible but I can tell you how to write concise code,

```
private string getFirstCPUID() =>
    new ManagementClass("win32_processor")
      .GetInstances()
      .FirstOrDefault()?
      .Properties["processorID"]?
      .Value?.ToString();
```

Comment: The problem is not is his/her coding style is elegant or not. This answer does not attempt to solve the problem

Comment: I have literally mentioned that it doesn't. I'm just showing him how to concisely express his intentions using new syntax and language features, which is an important aspect of software development too.

Comment: It would be a decent comment.